# Intuition as to why $ \operatorname{Ker}(A)^{\bot} = \operatorname{Im}(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So I came across this theorem stating that for a general Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

$$ \operatorname{Ker}(A)^{\bot} =  \operatorname{Im}(A^T)$$

with the proof:

> Let $x \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$, then that is equivalent to
>
> $\iff A \cdot x = 0$
>
> $\iff \forall i \in \{1, ...,m\}$ for the rows $b_i^T$ of $A$: $\langle b_i , x \rangle = 0$
>
> $\iff \forall y \in \operatorname{span}(b_1,...b_m)$: $\langle y , x \rangle = 0$
>
> $\iff x \bot  \operatorname{span}b_1,...,b_m) =  \operatorname{Im}(A^T)$
>
> $\iff x \in  \operatorname{Im}(A^T)^{\bot}$
>
> now the statement follows by taking the orthogonal complement

Now I understand all the steps in the proof but it won't click in my brain. Is there some geometric intuition or maybe an image to this that explains\demonstrates why this is true? Any source is also appreciated.

Comment: No intuition. It's just a consequence of how adjoint operators are defined in inner product spaces. The matrices wrt  orthonormal bases get transposed.

Comment: Maybe a way to imagine it geometrically then? I struggle to memorize things I don't understand and right now linear algebra is killing me with these kind of theorems

Comment: @Henno Brandsma It depends what you call "intuition". I propose something that helps to see this kind of duality using SVD.

Comment: @JeanMarie Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (Singular Value Decomposition) of $A$:

$$A=U \Sigma V^T\tag{1}$$

provides a good way to understand this kind of "exchange".

Indeed, as well explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2300482),

- the first columns of $U$ (corresponding to the non-zero singular values) constitute a basis of the range of $A$,
- the last colums of $V$ (corresponding to the zero singular values) constitute a basis of the kernel of $A$,

Now, transposing (1),
$$A^T=V \Sigma^TU^T,$$

ranges and kernels are exchanged: the new $U$ is the old $V$ and the new $V$ is the old $U$.

See as well my recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4073928) displaying the "intimate relationship" between $A$, $A^T$, $AA^T$, $A^TA$ seen through "SVD glasses"...